# How to rotate the numbers on Axes using Python Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

There's a scatter plot drawn with Matplotlib which has more points than the bottom axis can contain, so the numbers start overlapping each other, is there a way to rotate them to a certain degree or at least make them vertical? Looking at the Doc, I've found a way for rotating the labels but is there a way for rotating the numbers too?

The final result I'm thinking of is something like this:

[image: final-result]

And in case that's not possible, is there a way to show the numbers specified with range only, and hide the exact x coordinates of all points? (That's exactly the behavior I get if I use pre-specified numbers, for example, if the x axis is from 0 to 20, puts 0, 5, 10, 15 and 20 on the x axis.

But in this diagram, I'm getting the points from an api (a live plot) so the points are added continuously and for some reasons matplotlib is behaving differently and doesn't put the range limits I've specified on the x axis from the beginning. Instead, it keeps putting the x-coordinate of all numbers on the x-axis which makes them overlap.

```
import requests
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

fig = plt.figure()
location_axes = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

xs = []
ys = []

def get_current_location(i):
  response = requests.get("http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json")
  response_json = response.json()
  if(response.status_code == 200):
    location_axes.clear()
    xs.append(response_json['iss_position']['longitude'])
    ys.append(response_json['iss_position']['latitude'])
    location_axes.scatter(
      xs,
      ys
    )
  else:
    raise ConnectionError("A connection error occured while retrieving the data")

location_axes.set_xlim([-180,180])
location_axes.set_ylim([-90,90])
plt.grid(True)
# plt.xtick(rotation=45)

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, get_current_location, interval=1000)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with the following:

```
plt.xtick(rotation=45)
```

If you want it to be vertical you can also do:

```
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
```

You can read more about the rotation in the following documnatation:

https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/ticks_and_spines/ticklabels_rotation.html

https://kite.com/python/answers/how-to-rotate-axis-labels-in-matplotlib-in-python

## Edit

After you added your code please notice that you should do the following because the manipulation you wish is performed on `Axes` object:

```
location_axes.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=45)
```

add this to your function which you call during the animation:

```
def get_current_location(i):
  response = requests.get("http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json")
  response_json = response.json()
  if(response.status_code == 200):
    location_axes.clear()
    xs.append(response_json['iss_position']['longitude'])
    ys.append(response_json['iss_position']['latitude'])
    location_axes.scatter(
      xs,
      ys
    )
    location_axes.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=45)
  else:
    raise ConnectionError("A connection error occured while retrieving the data")
```

Comment: Thanks David, I've tried that, but I get "module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'xtick'" (I'm using the latest version of Matplotlib).

Comment: @aderchox that's weird, can you add your entire code to the question body; xtick should work

Comment: Thanks but have you tried it? It's still showing the X axis numbers horizontally for me.

Comment: rotation isn't listed here: https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params

Comment: @aderchox look at the update, you probably didn't call it properly; It worked for me